# Login viralstyle.com get data

Tags: c#, authentication

I want login to website and get html code after login successful.
https://viralstyle.com/login

> Error: remote server returned an error 500  line: HttpWebResponse
>   webResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

```cs
string email = "email@email.com";
string pw = "mypassword";
string PostData = String.Format("email={0}&password={1}&remember=0", email, pw);

CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://viralstyle.com/login");

req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentLength = PostData.Length;
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] loginDataBytes = encoding.GetBytes(PostData);
req.ContentLength = loginDataBytes.Length;
Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(loginDataBytes, 0, loginDataBytes.Length);

HttpWebResponse webResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

Stream datastream = webResp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream);
webBrowser1.DocumentText = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Sounds like there's an error on the server, not in your code.  Any way of finding out what that error is?  Unless whoever maintains the server can help you, all you can do is guesswork and reverse engineering of manual requests.  Using something like Fiddler, capture the HTTP requests made when you use the website manually and the ones made from your code and compare them.  If one works and another doesn't then there must be some difference between the two.  You'll need to find that difference.

Comment: Can you explain what data you are trying to get? We may have an API endpoint you can use to access it.

Comment: thank u !  i want get "my profit" and the number of items sold. http://q01.imgup.net/vt5ad7.png